# XSL and Flash XML breaks escaping

Tags: flash, xml-encoding

I have an XSL file I am loading in flash that includes the following snippet:

```
<xsl:text>&#x2022;</xsl:text>
```

I load it this way:

```
_root.brochure_xsl = new XML();
_root.brochure_xsl.onLoad = function() {
    _root.SendPdfXml();
}
_root.brochure_xsl.ignoreWhite = true;
_root.brochure_xsl.load(_root.appSettings.XmlDataLocation +"xml/brochure.xsl");
```

On the event, I trace the results like such:

```
send_lv.XslContent = _root.brochure_xsl.toString();
trace(send_lv.XslContent);
```

In the result trace, it converts the snippet to a bullet.

```
<xsl:text>
```

*

```
</xsl:text>
```

I want it to stay the encoded, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by not using the XML object. Instead just used a URL Loader.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly an encoding issue. The `toString()` method is suspect, but you have to check. Can you dump the contents of the XML character-by-character.

Answer (score 1):

What if you encode it twice in the XML:

```
<xsl:text>&amp;#x2022;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a hack.  Your code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.  As soon as your XML is parsed, the &#x2022 entity is decoded into the matching unicode character, then your XSL just prints on that character.